# Jquery Validate plugin. Show only a message by type of error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have some inputs created dynamically. 
All of them are 'required'. But I want to show the message only once.

```
 $("#FORMULARIO").validate({
            onfocusout: false,
            onkeyup: false,
            onclick: false,
            errorLabelContainer: "#divError",
            wrapper: "li",
            rules: {                
                Fecha_Inicio: {
                    required: true,
                    DateFormat: true
                },
                Fecha_Fin: {
                    required: true,
                    DateFormat: true
                },
                chkIdioma:{
                    required: true
                },
                Cod_Expediente_Interno_Caracter:
                    {
                        required: true
                    },
                Fecha_Solicitud:{
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages:
                {
                    Fecha_Inicio:'REQUIRED!',
                    Fecha_Fin:'REQUIRED!',
                    chkIdioma:'REQUIRED!',
                    Cod_Expediente_Interno_Caracter:'REQUIRED!',
                    Fecha_Solicitud:'REQUIRED!'
                },
            // Mostrar * al lado de los errores
            showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {                
                var label ;
                if (this.errorList.length > 0) {
                    for (var x = 0; x < this.errorList.length; x++) {    
                        if ($('#lblError' + errorList[x].element.id).length) 
                        {
                        }
                        else{
                            label = $("<label class='error' id='lblError" + errorList[x].element.id + "'>*</label>");
                            label.insertAfter(errorList[x].element);    
                        }
                    }
                }
                this.defaultShowErrors();
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                alert("ok");
            }
        });   
        $.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
            required: 'REQUIRED!',
            DateFormat: 'DATE INCORRECT!',
            digits: 'NOT A DIGIT!',
            number: 'NOT A NUMBER!'
        });


        $("input[name^=Campo_]").each(function () { 

            $(this).rules('add', 'required');

        }); 
        $("input[name^=ListaValor_]").each(function () { 

            $(this).rules('add', "required");

        }); 

        $.validator.addMethod("DateFormat", function (value, element) { return (this.optional(element) || ValidaFecha(value)); }, "NOT A DATE");
```

They are displayed like this

•REQUIRED!
•REQUIRED!
•REQUIRED!
•REQUIRED!
•REQUIRED!

I want to display the error only once for all inputs required on the form.

On the `showErrors` property I show a '*' behind each input.
And the messages are displayed on a `div` that I define on `errorLabelContainer` property.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the rest of your code?  Instead of telling us about `showErrors` and `errorLabelContainer`, ***show*** them in the `.validate()` call; and along with the relevant HTML.

Comment: You are right. I just updated the code.
Thanks